# How to update the states after Component remounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-state, react-state-management

I am trying to update a Component's state when re-mounted.

Example: the `A` Component, containing the `d` state.

1. `A` mounted and I can update the `d` state.
2. `A` unmounted.
3. `A` again mounted.
   Now updating the `d` does not work.

I actually have file uploading `progress` some time users during uploading go back to the previous page, while the Component is unmounted and uploading is not canceled. So the user can open again the page as already was closed.

So here the update does not work and I am not able to show the `progress` in state.

Comment: State resets when a component is unmounted. To keep the state, move it up the tree.

Comment: @Muhammad ... what about storing `progress` in a global-state like `redux-store`

Comment: do you have a code example of your current implementation?

Comment: @ChrisG, just the code is big moving to top of the tree, need more time more care

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli, that is a solutions, but progressing and updating in global force to re-render all the app, that's why I am not considering as of now

Comment: @Muhammad **updating in global force to re-render all the app** <-- that's not true, Muhammad ... you have the control over what component to re-render

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli, you are right just here is a huge code and need more time to be take care all part of the app by the way thank you that is a solution